# Playing game on Xbox One with friend on Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox-network

I am considering buying an Xbox One console, but the main reason for doing so is to play a game with a friend who owns the Xbox 360. Is it possible to play together over the internet between the two consoles, assuming that the game is compatible with the newer version console? There is a lot of conflicting information about that, particularly since it appears as though backwards compatibility is only now becoming available.

EDIT: The games in question are kinect sports, kinect sports 2 and kinect adventures

Comment: This would depend greatly on the gam, I suspect. If you have one in mind, please add it to the question.

Comment: Just as a heads-up: Microsoft will eventually take down the servers for the Xbox 360, just like they did with the original Xbox. So - in the long run - you won't be able to play online with other Xbox 360 owners, even if you own an Xbox 360 yourself. That's something you should keep in mind.

Comment: I just assumed that the game in question would be Destiny.

Comment: Close voters, this is only broad in a sense of us not knowing the game. Since OP asks us to assume the game is compatible with the xbox one, so this is not an issue. Past this restriction, they will play together, provided OP is still using an xbox 360 game.

Comment: Someone should confirm, but I think destiny is, regardless. At the least, you use the same character across generations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are playing an xbox 360 game on the xbox one, through backwards compatibility, your xbox will still be using 360 servers. As such, multiplayer should work, regardless.

Comment: Ill try to improve this answer when I get home, but direct quotes from the backwards compatibility FAQ confirm this, and I have also confirmed this with a Microsoft rep.

Comment: Microsoft Reps are not always a positive source of information but that FAQ should answer. I havent tried any kinect games myself because of the fact that I don't have the new XBONE Kinect. I can confirm that you can play multiplayer in Gears.